# Fetching data from ElasticSeach NEST C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

So my goal is to use ElasticSearch, ES, as a log. To be more specific, i want to upload basically just a timestamp from when my application last ran. The uploading works fine but i cannot figure out how to fetch the data from the index. I've tried both using the Query and Aggregetion but in neither of cases have I managed to get some data. I get a response that says :

> Valid NEST response built from a low level call on POST: /lastrun/lastrun/_search.

I have also tried searching for solutions but cannot manage to find anything that works for me. Can anyone help me fetch the data?

The index name is 'lastrun' and the class I upload to the index is called `LastRun`.

The Logger class

```
    public static Boolean WriteLastRun()
    {
        var response = Elastic.Index(new LastRun { Date = DateTime.Now });
        return response.IsValid ? true : false;
    }

    public static DateTime ReadLastRun()
    {
        var SearchResponse = Elastic.Search<LastRun>(s => s
                                                       .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
                                                       .Index("lastrun"));
        Console.WriteLine(SearchResponse.Documents);
        return new DateTime();
    }
```

The LastRun class I upload to ES.

```
public class LastRun
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Settings for the Elastic:

```
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/")).DefaultIndex('lastrun');
        ElasticClient Elastic = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

**EDIT 2**
I can verify that the same index is being uploaded to and searched by this code and by checking the same index in kibana.

```
        var resolver = new IndexNameResolver(settings);
        var index = resolver.Resolve<LastRun>();
        Console.WriteLine(index); //prints 'lastrun'
```

Comment: When you index a `LastRun`, what index is being used? What does the configuration of `Elastic` look like? Can you edit and add it to your question?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by 'what index is being used?' As for the settings, give me a min.

Comment: With `Elastic.Index(new LastRun { Date = DateTime.Now });`, which index in Elasticsearch is this `LastRun` instance going to be indexed into? On the search request, `"lastrun"` is specified as the index to search, but no index is specified for the index operation.

Comment: It writes to the same index, the 'lastrun' index. I verified this the same way as in the second edit.

Comment: OK. Are you trying to search as it as soon as it's indexed? The document will not be available to search until after `refresh_interval` (default 1 second). You can fetch documents as soon as they are indexed using `Get<T>()` and `MultiGet<T>()`

Comment: There is already some docs in the index so time interval shouldn't be a problem. However, I cannot find the documentation of `Get` in the latest version. Would you mind linking it?

Comment: Here's the get documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html

Comment: Take a look at the NEST troubleshooting section to see what is being returned from Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Solved it! Apparently there wasn't a problem from the beginning. I just had the wrong way of iterating through the response. Thank you for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there wasn't a problem from the beginning. The Search method worked fine and I had the wrong ideá of accessing the doc in the respons.

This is what is did, which was wrong:

```
Console.WriteLine(SearchResponse.Documents);
```

And here the right way to do it:

```
foreach (var item in SearchResponse.Documents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Date) 
        }
```